# md Select required

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to load a mdDialog setting a parameter (product in this case), and when it loads (md selects included) It says those fields are required, and doesn't stop until I change the option.

The code is :

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm style="min-width: 150px;">
                    <label>Expiration type</label>
                    <md-select name="expirationType" placeholder="Expiration" ng-model="product.expirationType" ng-required='product.name'>
                        <md-option value="1">Only Expiry date</md-option>
                        <md-option value="2">Only Shelflife</md-option>
                        <md-option value="3">Expiry Date & Shelflife</md-option>
                        <md-option value="4">Non Expirable</md-option>
                    </md-select>
                    <div ng-messages="productForm.expirationType.$error" role="alert">
                        <div ng-message="required">You must supply a value.</div>
                    </div>
                </md-input-container>
```

And the JS :

```
   function EditDialogController($scope, $mdDialog, $mdToast, $log, $http, manufacturers, product) {


        $scope.product = product;
```

(edit) 
I'm guessing it has something to do with the ng-Pristine or the ng-dirty attributes, in another similar case when I change the product through a function(Activated by a button), material considers that the element is changed, so it's valid. Is there a way to launch a function AFTER the mdDialog is loaded?

Comment: Please remove ng-required in try it

Comment: Already tried with ng-required=true and with required, still no dice